# Animating letters in an already animated cell (of a table)

Tags: beamer, formatting, overlays

I am a newbie to `beamer`. I want to animate some cells (the corner cells) of my table to become blue during a presentation. I then want some letters in those cells to be animated to green. Can someone please help me code this?

Your help is very much appreciated.

```
\documentclass[t,xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,automata} 


\newcommand<>{\mywordeee}[1]{%
    \alt#2{\textcolor{green}{{#1}}}{\widthofbold{#1}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand<>{\mycel}[1]{%
    \alt#2{\cellcolor{blue!25}{{#1}}}{\widthofbold{#1}}}
\makeatother  


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{table}[H]
        \footnotesize\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
        \tiny\begin{center}
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
                $\theta_2^5$ & \mycel<2>{ ($\mywordeee<2,3>{D},C$)} & ($D,C$) & ($D,C$) & ($C,C$), ($D,C$) & \mycel<2>{($C,C$)}   \\ \cline{1-6}
                $\theta_2^4$ & ($D,C$) & ($C,D$), ($D,C$)  & ($C,D$), ($D,C$)& ($C,D$), ($D,C$), ($C,C$)& ($C,C$), ($C,D$) \\ \cline{1-6}
                $\theta_2^3$ & ($D,C$) & ($C,D$), ($D,C$) & ($C,D$), ($D,C$) & ($C,D$), ($D,C$)& ($C,D$) \\ \cline{1-6}
                $\theta_2^2$ & ($D,D$), ($D,C$) & ($D,D$), ($D,C$), ($C,D$) & ($C,D$), ($D,C$)& ($C,D$), ($D,C$)& ($C,D$) \\\cline{1-6} 
                $\theta_2^1$ & \mycel<2>{($\mywordeee<2,3-4>{D},D$)} & ($D,D$), ($C,D$) & ($C,D$) & ($C,D$)& \mycel<2>{($C,D$)} \\ \hline 
                & $\theta_1^1$ & $\theta_1^2$ & $\theta_1^3$ & $\theta_1^4$ & $\theta_1^5$ \\ \hline  
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
        \end{table}


    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: How you like to animate? all corner cells in once (as is obtain from your code now) or cell by cell? And please complete your code, now gives error (and begin/end document are missing)

Comment: Thank you. I'd like to animate it all corner cells at once and after that, I want to change the colour of certain characters in te coloured cells one by one.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer here? If so, could you please describe in a little more detail the desired animation for the characters in the colorized cells?